# Port Qt and QML to qt5 and qt quick 2.1

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

Recently my leader  assign me one Qt and qml port work. Our old project is work on Qt 4.8 and using Qt quick 1.0.  At Qt4 QML natively does not provide any default GUI controls to be utilized in interface creation for any operating system it supports. To save on creating owner-drawn controls, we chose to use Qt Components for Desktop project as base for all our GUI to create OS-standard (and depended) look and feel on Qt4.8.  Qt Components are renamed to Qt Quick Controls and are developed for Qt5.x.  The Qt Components provide the menu , toolbar, button.  So I remove the Qt Components because Qt5.x have the ApplicationWindow.

main.qml file:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    title: "My Application"

    Button {
        text: "Push Me"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Main.cpp file:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine("main.qml");
    QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
    QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);
    if ( !window ) {
        qWarning("Error: Your root item has to be a Window.");
        return -1;
    }
    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

But in our old project, in the main function, we have one `MainWindow` which implements main window, locates `main.qml` and creates `QDeclarativeView` with `main.qml` as source.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    ……
}
```

In the constructor of `MainWindow`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ……
    DeclarativeView* pView = new DeclarativeView;
    setCentralWidget(pView);
    ……
}
```

The Declarativeview implements `DeclarativeView` class which inherits `QDeclarativeView` and keeps pointer to its parent `QWidget`. `MainWindow` can modify the menu dynamically. When click one menu item, one dialog will be created, the dialog is defined by qml file or Qt ui file.

Now I have finished all the Qml file poring work, replace the Qt Components with QtQuick.Controls 1.0. But I don’t know how I use `QQmlApplicationEngine` to load my file and modify the menu dynamically, load you qt ui class widget, use `QQuickWindow` to load new qml file to open the new window.

I think we needn't use the widget in the my new project. Could you give me some help? Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 1):

In a typical QtQuick application you do not have any QWidget functionality available. This means [QMainWindow](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qmainwindow.html), [QMenuBar](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qmenubar.html) or [QMenu](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qmenu.html) can not be used, since they inherit `QWidget`.

The way to go is to append a QML menu in the `ApplicationWindow`:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    title: "My Application"
    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            id: menuA
            title: "Menu A"

            MenuItem {
                text: "Hello 1"
            }
            MenuItem {
                text: "Hello 2"
            }
        }
        Menu {
            title: "Menu B"

            MenuItem {
                text: "Hello 3"
            }
            MenuItem {
                text: "Hello 4"
            }
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {
            var newMenuItem = menuA.addItem("bla")
        }
    }
}
```

This example shows a way to dynamically add a `MenuItem` using Javascript in QML. I just didn't figure out how to set any functionality for the new menu entry, but I think this can be done using the `action` property of [MenuItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qml-qtquick-controls1-menuitem.html).

Comment: Yes you're right. You have to define actions and then assign them to the MenuItem's action. Like this:

// ...

Action {
    id: exitAction
    text: qsTr("Exit")
}

menuBar: MenuBar {
    Menu {
        title: qsTr("File")
        MenuItem { action: exitAction }
    }
}

// ...